# How to convert html_Table to pandas dataframe in Dash using python?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I have a pandas dataframe in Dash which is converted to HTML before being returned to html.Div() using the below function -

```
def generate_table(dataframe, max_rows=10):
    return html.Table(
        # Header
        [html.Tr([html.Th(col) for col in dataframe.columns])] +

        # Body
        [html.Tr([
            html.Td(dataframe.iloc[i][col]) for col in dataframe.columns
        ]) for i in range(min(len(dataframe), max_rows))]
    )
```

This will again be an Input in a callback, where I need to convert the html table to a dataframe to allow me to perform calculations on its columns. I have tried this - [did not help though]

```
@app.callback(
    [Output("newtable", "children")],
    [Input("mastertable", "children"),
     ])
def performcalc(x):
    if not x is None:
        tb = pd.read_html(str([x])) # this is not working
        ## Perfomr calculations on dataframe ##
        return [tb]
    return None
```

How can I convert the html input to a pandas dataframe?

Also, last row of the table is going to be an summary row, that is, sum of the respective columns. I would like to pass a line separating the values from the summary row when I return it to the Div. Something like this -

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
 1     2     3
 3     2     1
----------------
 4     4     4
```

Thank you for your help is advance.

Comment: Do you have to use an html table? Could you use a [Dash datatable](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable) instead? That would make this process immensely easier.

Comment: I have not tried datatable. So can a rendered datatable converted back to dataframe? or is it possible to perform operations on the data table itself? Can you provide a sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @coralvanda for your suggestion. Using Dash tables solved the problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import dash_table as dt

## Render dataframe as datatable
# Where, DF = pd.DataFrame object
dt.DataTable(
    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in DF.columns],
    data=DF.to_dict('records')
)
## Convert datatable from an Input in callback function to dataframe.
# Where x is callback input

finalDF = pd.DataFrame(x['props']['data'])
```